# How do I make the computer process the loop, then iterate the print statements the other way round in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a python program that converts decimal to binary.
Here's what I made -

```
dec = 22
while dec > 0:
    i = (dec % 2)
    print (i, end = '')
    dec = dec // 2
```

The output's 01101. I require 10110. How do I do it?

PS:- I just started coding 2 weeks ago. Forgive me if the answer is obvious or what I'm asking is impossible.

Comment: 1. You need to debug it if the output is wrong. 2. Very little is outright impossible in programming. It's usually just a question of difficultly.

Comment: `bin(22)[2:]` would solve your task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of iterate print statement in reverse, you can save the result in variable, maybe something like this

```
dec = 22 #1
result = '' #2
while dec > 0: #3
    i = (dec % 2) #4
    result = str(i) + result #5
    dec = dec // 2 #6
print(result) #7
```

**EDIT**, add explanation

There are additional line 2 and 7 from your original code, and change in line 5.

In line 2, we declare a variable named result where we initialize it with empty string.

On line 5, we convert i to string with **str(i)**, then append it, **+** in front of previous **result**. Here is where you can arrange your result, either before the previous (**str(i) + result**) or after previous result (**result + str(i)**)

On line 7, we simply print the content of the **result** variable

Comment: @Carcigenicate: Sorry, what do you mean? I'm not get it.

Comment: ah forget to cast the int to str, thanks for pointing it out @Miriam

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [extended slice](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html) syntax:

```
dec = 22
result = ''
while dec > 0:
    i = (dec % 2)
    result += str(i)
    dec = dec // 2

print (int(result[::-1]))
```